# Why is the time complexity of the following maximum bipartite matching implementation O(m*n^2)?

Tags: performance, algorithm, time-complexity, matching, bipartite

There is this library that has implementations of many algorithms and one of them is maximum bipartite matching.

Here is the link to the source code: http://shygypsy.com/tools/bpm.cpp

I will include it here as well(without the comments)

```
#include <string.h>

#define M 128
#define N 128

bool graph[M][N];
bool seen[N];
int matchL[M], matchR[N];
int n, m;

bool bpm( int u )
 {
  for( int v = 0; v < n; v++ ) 
   if( graph[u][v] )
   {
    if( seen[v] ) continue;
    seen[v] = true;

    if( matchR[v] < 0 || bpm( matchR[v] ) )
    {
        matchL[u] = v;
        matchR[v] = u;
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}

int main()
{
  memset( matchL, -1, sizeof( matchL ) );
  memset( matchR, -1, sizeof( matchR ) );
  int cnt = 0;
  for( int i = 0; i < m; i++ )
  {
      memset( seen, 0, sizeof( seen ) );
      if( bpm( i ) ) cnt++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

We have a for loop that runs `m` times. The number `m` refers to the amount of workers.
Then we enter the `bpm` function which has another for loop. This loop runs `n` times where `n` is the amount of tasks.

Until now we have `m*n` time complexity.

However there is a recursive function call of `bpm` in the third if statement. The goal of this function is to run a `dfs` in order to find an augmented path.

I know that `dfs` has a time complexity `O(n+m)`. So I would assume that the function `bpm` has a complexity of `O(n+m)`

Thus the total time complexity would be `O(m*(n+m))`

However the author says it's `O(m*n^2)`. Can someone explain me why is this the case? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd note that `O(m*(n+m)) == O(n*m^2)`, so is there any chance that you and the author have interchanged the symbols?

Comment: If I understand correct, m is the number of workers and n the number of tasks, I was wrong about the time complexity of the DFS, what dfb said is most likely correct because

O(m*n + n + m) is the time complexity of the DFS and so the final complexity will be

O(n*m*n + n*n + n*m) = O(m*n^2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables are somewhat confusing here: M and N refer to the number of nodes on each side of the graph.  The runtime of DFS is `O(E+V)` where E is the number of edges.  In a bipartite graph |E| is at most N*M and V will be (N+M), thus your DFS is going to take `O(NM)`.   The total time complexity is then `O(NM^2)`.  Not sure where the `N^2` comes in, could be a typo...

Comment: thank you, I got a little confused with the DFS time complexity, your explanation makes sense to me.